# How does the Google Web Starter Kit implement automatic browser reloading?

Tags: web-development

How does the [Google Web Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/starter-kit/) implement automatic browser reload when the html is changed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about **[webmastering as defined in the FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats a built-in [browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/) of gulp, located in gulpfile.babel.js